# sqlalchemy join to self with intermediate table (working sql, not sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlite, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to perform a many-to-many join with an intermediate table. (first select row(s) in Items, join to Attribution on FK, then join with the other FK in attribution to get more from Items) Schema looks like this:

```
class Items(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    project = Column(Integer)
    linkid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("items.linkid"))

    linked = relationship("Items", foreign_keys="[Items.linkid]")

class Attribution(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attribution"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link_id_d = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.linkid'))
    link_id_m = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.linkid'))
```

And the query looks like this:

```
final_items = aliased(Items)
proj_1 = session.query(Items)\
    .join(Attribution, ( (Items.name=="upper_third") & (Attribution.link_id_m==Items.linkid) ))\
    .join(final_items, final_items.linkid==Attribution.link_id_d)\
    .all()
```

This provides only one row; output:

```
upper_third 1
```

The sql I am using through sqlite, which provides the expected three rows, looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items
join attribution on items.name = 'upper_third' and items.linkid == attribution.link_id_m
join items as tbl1 on tbl1.linkid == attribution.link_id_d
```

Output:

```
5|upper_third|1|1|1|2|1|2|lower_first|2|2
5|upper_third|1|1|1|2|1|4|lower_second|2|2
5|upper_third|1|1|1|2|1|6|lower_third|2|2
```

What is the logical difference between these two queries, and how can I migrate the sql solution to sqalchemy?

(Full runnable code to generate sqlite database and test queries is below)

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, UniqueConstraint, ForeignKey, func, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, aliased, backref

Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, Text, Table

class Items(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    project = Column(Integer)
    linkid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("items.linkid"))

    linked = relationship("Items", foreign_keys="[Items.linkid]")
    attributions_m = relationship("Attribution", foreign_keys="[Attribution.link_id_m]")
    attributions_d = relationship("Attribution", foreign_keys="[Attribution.link_id_d]")

class Attribution(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attribution"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link_id_d = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.linkid'))  # one of the tests to link to
    link_id_m = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.linkid'))  # one of the tests to link to


import os


if os.path.exists('app.db'):
    os.remove('app.db')

engine = create_engine('sqlite+pysqlite:///app.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


u1 = Items(name="upper_first", linkid=1, project=1)
l1 = Items(name="lower_first", linkid=2, project=2)

u2 = Items(name="upper_second", linkid=1, project=1)
l2 = Items(name="lower_second", linkid=2, project=2)

u3 = Items(name="upper_third", linkid=1, project=1)
l3 = Items(name="lower_third", linkid=2, project=2)

session.add(u1)
session.add(l1)
session.add(u2)
session.add(l2)
session.add(u3)
session.add(l3)

session.commit()

a1 = Attribution(link_id_m=u3.linkid, link_id_d=l3.linkid)
session.add(a1)
session.commit()

final_items = aliased(Items)
proj = session.query(Items)\
    .join(Attribution, ( (Items.name=="upper_third") & (Attribution.link_id_m==Items.linkid) ))\
    .join(final_items, final_items.linkid==Attribution.link_id_d)\
    .all()

for l in proj:
    print(l.name, l.linkid)
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html all() "will deduplicate entries based on primary key" PS Have you researched?  Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy To ask / answer the question "have you researched" I don't think is a productive question. In general, getting information by asking a question on SO is a 'last resort' kind of approach for me. Basically every other method is faster. So I try to google significantly before asking. However, your search terms differ from mine based on many factors, and in this case you were able to find the information I needed in your documentation link. This is why it helps to have a second set of eyes take a look. If you post your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: You did not need any help to google 'sqlalchemy .all()' which is what I did. Read the manual for the features you are using. Also it doesn't matter what you are using, put a [mre] in your code questions.

Comment: The reason why the base & result table contents should be echoed & cut & pasted into your post is so 1. it is more likely that the post contains the actual input, code & output that belong together & 2. the post is self-contained. Similarly I suggested that you show SQL select \* & python echo of both bases since 1. it shows what is actually the input of the queries & that the initialization code is correct 2. it shows your python read is correct. This pins down where the problem(s) can be. PS Glad to hear you researched.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer: SQLAlchemy working as expected.**

*The key culprit is the fact that when you query for an mapped Model, you will get instances of the model as a result. If the same model is returned multiple times, SA will make sure to return each only once, and this is why you have only 1 row returned instead of 3 expected.*

You can see this by the difference in the SQL you construct (`select * ...`) vs the one SA creates for you (`select items.*`; SA does not create `*`, but the point is that it selects only from the `items` table.

The solution is to add also other entities to the `query(...)` to be returned:

```
final_items = aliased(Items, name="FinalItems")
proj = (
    session
    .query(Items, Attribution, final_items)  # IMPORTANT !!!
    .join(Attribution, ( (Items.name=="upper_third") & (Attribution.link_id_m==Items.linkid) ))
    .join(final_items, final_items.linkid==Attribution.link_id_d)
)
```

Running it as below:

```
for l in proj.all():
    print(l)
    # print(l.Items, l.Attribution, l.FinalItems)  # also can access models using names.
```

... will result in a list of `tuple(Items, Attribution, Items)`:

```
(<Items(id=5, linkid=1, name='upper_third', project=1)>, <Attribution(id=1, link_id_d=2, link_id_m=1)>, <Items(id=2, linkid=2, name='lower_first', project=2)>)
(<Items(id=5, linkid=1, name='upper_third', project=1)>, <Attribution(id=1, link_id_d=2, link_id_m=1)>, <Items(id=4, linkid=2, name='lower_second', project=2)>)
(<Items(id=5, linkid=1, name='upper_third', project=1)>, <Attribution(id=1, link_id_d=2, link_id_m=1)>, <Items(id=6, linkid=2, name='lower_third', project=2)>)
```

If you really wanted to have the columns returned as in your example, you could execute the `statement` of the query. The below code

```
for row in session.execute(proj.statement):
    print(row)
```

will return:

```
(5, 'upper_third', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 'lower_first', 2, 2)
(5, 'upper_third', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 'lower_second', 2, 2)
(5, 'upper_third', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 'lower_third', 2, 2)
```